# Не выводятся данные на JSP-страницу в checkbox value из БД

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, jsp, jstl

При попытке вывода данных из БД в checkbox на JSP-страничку вот в таком виде:

```
Roles:     
<c:forEach var="role" items="${roleList}">
        <div class="roleInputId">
            <input type="checkbox" name="rolesId" value="${role.idRole}"/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rolesName" value="${role.nameOfRole}"/>
        </c:forEach>
```

Данные не выводятся в checkbox, но если вид такой:

```
Roles:
            <c:forEach var="role" items="${roleList}">
            <div class="roleInputId">
                <input type="checkbox" name="rolesId" value="${role.idRole}"/><c:out value="${role.idRole}"/>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rolesName" value="${role.nameOfRole}"/><c:out value="${role.nameOfRole}"/>
            </c:forEach>
```

Данные есть. Но суть в том, что вывод должен быть именно в value, чтобы эти значения можно было потом забрать. Подскажите, как можно исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постараюсь ответить вам.

Вам необходимо сгенерировать `label` для каждого `checkbox`. Поскольку `checkbox` сам по себе только квадратик на который можно поставить галочку.

```js
function getValues(){
  console.log([...$('.roleInputId>input:checked')].map(item=>$(item).val()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="roleInputId">
 <input id="rolesId_1" type="checkbox" value="value_1"/><label for="rolesId_1">Some Text 1</label>
 <input id="rolesId_2" type="checkbox" value="value_2"/><label for="rolesId_2">Some Text 2</label>
 <input id="rolesId_3" type="checkbox" value="value_3"/><label for="rolesId_3">Some Text 2</label>
</div>

<button onclick="getValues()">get values</button>
```